# laravel 9 - Call to undefined method App\Models\User::create() with KeycloakUser

Tags: php, laravel

I have a new Laravel 9 application and I am trying to use Keycloak as an SSO.
I am using [this package](https://github.com/mariovalney/laravel-keycloak-web-guard) to achieve that. I created the migrations and the seeders to have some data. I am using my own user model extending the [KeycloakUser](https://github.com/mariovalney/laravel-keycloak-web-guard#how-to-implement-my-model) provided by the package.

My seeder does not run and I get this error message:

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\User::create()
```

**My Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Vizir\KeycloakWebGuard\Models\KeycloakUser;

class User extends KeycloakUser
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'surname',
        'email',
        'role',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the company that owns the user.
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the comments for the user.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

}
```

**The migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('company_id')->nullable();
            $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin', 'superadmin'])->default('user');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

**The seeder**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\User;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        User::create([
            'firstname' => 'Aaaa',
            'surname' => 'Bbbb',
            'email' => 'ab@first.com',
            'role' => 'superadmin',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your migration and password field is required

Comment: User::create([
            'firstname' => 'Aaaa',
            'surname'   => 'Bbbb',
            'email'     => 'ab@first.com',
            'role'      => 'superadmin',
            'password'  => 'superadmin',
        ]);

Comment: @Md.DelowarHossen did you mean 'password' => bycrypt('superadmin') ?

Comment: Have you laravel migration?

Comment: the create method is part of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, which you normally need to extend your `App\Models\Model` class to , and it seems `KeyclockUser` does not event extends the required Model class , not sure why, instead it implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is copy KeycloakUser into app\Models.
Rename the file and class to User and than add extends Model.

namespace Vizir\KeycloakWebGuard\Models;

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
   .... 
   // all of these methods are originated from KeycloakUser
```

And dont forget to adjust your `config/auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'keycloak-users',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    // ...
]
```

Comment: I have an error when running my seeder: `Declaration of App\Models\User::__get(string $name) must be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__get($key)` And even if I replace `string $name` with `$key` I still have an error. `Too few arguments to function App\Models\User::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/User/Documents/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 2327 and exactly 1 expected`.

Comment: i notice from source code https://github.com/mariovalney/laravel-keycloak-web-guard/blob/master/src/Models/KeycloakUser.php , there is __construct(array $profile) , i'm not sure what this is, probably best to contact git owner